# empty list after using list comprehension

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, higher-order-functions

in my list comprehension, I am trying to remove`"RT @tiktoksaudi2:"`occurrences if it exists in a list, yet I get an empty list even though it doesn't exist in the list

```
test=["The way to a man's heart is through his stomach. - Sarah Willis Parton", 'A first rate soup is better than a second rate painting. - Abraham Maslow', 'A good cook is like a sorceress who dispenses happiness. - Elsa Schiaparelli', "A man's palate can, in time, become accustomed to anything. - Napoleon Bonaparte", 'Savory seasonings stimulate the appetite. - Latin Proverb', 'Cooking is an observation-based process that you can’t do if you’re so completely focused on a recipe. - Alton Brown', 'Happiness is finding three olives in your martini when you’re hungry. - Johnny Carson', 'A good meal makes a man feel more charitable toward the world than any sermon. - Arthur Pendenys', 'Wine and cheese are ageless companions, like aspirin and aches, or June and moon, or good people and noble ventures. - M. F. K. Fisher', 'For hunger is a sauce, well blended and prepared, for any food. - Chrétien de Troyes', "Without my morning coffee I'm just like a dried up piece of roast goat. - Johann Sebastian Bach", 'You know how I feel about tacos. It’s the only food shaped like a smile. A beef smile. - Earl Hickey']
        
print(test)
sh3rtext=[text.replace("RT @tiktoksaudi2:","") for text in test if "RT @tiktoksaudi2:" in text]
print(sh3rtext)
```

Comment: You get an empty list *because* it doesn't exist in the list - you only include items in the output that do include it. There's really no point to that condition, because replace won't change strings that don't contain it anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `if` clause in list comprehensions filters out any items that don't match the condition; ie. in your example, any items that don't contain "RT @tiktoksaudi2:" (-> all of them). Just leave out the `if "RT @tiktoksaudi2:" in text` and do the replace call on all elements (this will do nothing if an element doesn't contain your string and just return the original) to get the entire list back.

Comment: Thanks i see now, but how does it filter exactly? i thought it would will make the replace method work only if it was true

Comment: @sambob12 it first filters the list, returning a smaller (or empty) list, and then applies the replace function to all elements left. if you just want to execute the function on some elements while returning all of them, use smth like [(text.replace(...) if ... in text else text) for text in test]; however, as stated above, you can simply run replace on all elements

Comment: @sambob12 It does not even call the `replace` function if the condition (`"RT @tiktoksaudi2:" in text`) is not `True`.